# Group by Time via a Dynamic Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

Good day. I am trying to execute a query that grabs data and groups based on an interval which is a dynamic parameter ranging from 30-300 seconds. If the parameter is 45 then I would like the data to be grouped by 45 seconds.

Data is coming in at a rate of every 30 seconds. My query is not separating the date time field properly.Am I supposed to round dates? I am using the `DATEPART` function and dividing by the parameter which is dynamic. Is this the way I should be doing it? Any help is most appreciated.

QUERY

```
DECLARE @DStart DATETIME 
DECLARE @DStop DATETIME 
DECLARE @printInt INT 

SET @DStart = (SELECT TOP 1 Dateadd(millisecond, -250, dates) 
               FROM   tablea 
               WHERE  triggerval = 1 
                      AND recipenumber = 136--@SelectRecipe 
               ORDER  BY dates ASC) 
SET @DStop = (SELECT TOP 1 dates 
              FROM   tablea 
              WHERE  triggerval = 0 
                     AND recipenumber = 136--@SelectRecipe 
              ORDER  BY dates DESC) 

DECLARE @tbl8 TABLE 
  ( 
     processval          NVARCHAR(255) NULL, 
     processvariablename NVARCHAR(255) NULL, 
     dateentered         DATETIME NULL, 
     vcheck              INT NULL 
  ); 

INSERT INTO @tbl8 
SELECT processval, 
       b.processvariablename, 
       a.dateentered, 
       0 AS vCheck 
FROM   procv a 
       INNER JOIN procvname b 
               ON a.numid = b.numid 
WHERE  a.dateentered >= @DStart 
       AND a.dateentered <= @DStop 
       AND b.isvisible > 0 
GROUP  BY Datepart(second, 0, dateentered) / @printInt, 
          dateentered, 
          processval, 
          processvariablename 

SELECT * 
FROM   @tbl8
```

RAW SAMPLE DATA

```
0   2018-07-26 12:47:18.480
14.7514 2018-07-26 12:47:18.480
26.7243 2018-07-26 12:47:18.480
27.2616 2018-07-26 12:47:18.480
60.8281 2018-07-26 12:47:18.480
60.9732 2018-07-26 12:47:18.480
63.4687 2018-07-26 12:47:18.480
68.0573 2018-07-26 12:47:18.480
0   2018-07-26 12:47:48.213
14.7555 2018-07-26 12:47:48.213
26.7345 2018-07-26 12:47:48.213
27.2591 2018-07-26 12:47:48.213
60.8154 2018-07-26 12:47:48.213
60.9401 2018-07-26 12:47:48.213
63.4356 2018-07-26 12:47:48.213
68.1057 2018-07-26 12:47:48.213
0   2018-07-26 12:47:48.483
14.7555 2018-07-26 12:47:48.483
26.7345 2018-07-26 12:47:48.483
27.2591 2018-07-26 12:47:48.483
60.8154 2018-07-26 12:47:48.483
60.9401 2018-07-26 12:47:48.483
63.4356 2018-07-26 12:47:48.483
68.1057 2018-07-26 12:47:48.483
0   2018-07-26 12:48:18.483
21.1506 2018-07-26 12:48:18.483
27.0706 2018-07-26 12:48:18.483
27.1649 2018-07-26 12:48:18.483
61.3094 2018-07-26 12:48:18.483
61.8161 2018-07-26 12:48:18.483
64.7775 2018-07-26 12:48:18.483
70.0078 2018-07-26 12:48:18.483
0   2018-07-26 12:48:48.487
22.8971 2018-07-26 12:48:48.487
26.9688 2018-07-26 12:48:48.487
27.0859 2018-07-26 12:48:48.487
67.7925 2018-07-26 12:48:48.487
68.5385 2018-07-26 12:48:48.487
70.9347 2018-07-26 12:48:48.487
72.6892 2018-07-26 12:48:48.487
0   2018-07-26 12:49:18.487
23.5001 2018-07-26 12:49:18.487
26.9102 2018-07-26 12:49:18.487
30.5184 2018-07-26 12:49:18.487
68.867  2018-07-26 12:49:18.487
69.906  2018-07-26 12:49:18.487
71.5178 2018-07-26 12:49:18.487
84.3287 2018-07-26 12:49:18.487
0   2018-07-26 12:49:48.490
23.9836 2018-07-26 12:49:48.490
26.844  2018-07-26 12:49:48.490
36.8819 2018-07-26 12:49:48.490
71.0493 2018-07-26 12:49:48.490
71.9634 2018-07-26 12:49:48.490
73.7739 2018-07-26 12:49:48.490
93.7401 2018-07-26 12:49:48.490
0   2018-07-26 12:50:18.490
24.6327 2018-07-26 12:50:18.490
26.8567 2018-07-26 12:50:18.490
44.1773 2018-07-26 12:50:18.490
73.4811 2018-07-26 12:50:18.490
74.3621 2018-07-26 12:50:18.490
76.1497 2018-07-26 12:50:18.490
99.4975 2018-07-26 12:50:18.490
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If open to a helper function which dynamically creates date/time ranges, consider the following

You can pass the desired date part (YY,QQ,MM,WK,DD,HH,MI,SS) and the Increment

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeValue] Money,[SomeDateTime] datetime)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (0,'2018-07-26 12:47:18.480'),(14.7514,'2018-07-26 12:47:18.480'),(26.7243,'2018-07-26 12:47:18.480'),(27.2616,'2018-07-26 12:47:18.480'),(60.8281,'2018-07-26 12:47:18.480'),(60.9732,'2018-07-26 12:47:18.480'),(63.4687,'2018-07-26 12:47:18.480'),(68.0573,'2018-07-26 12:47:18.480')
,(0,'2018-07-26 12:47:48.213'),(14.7555,'2018-07-26 12:47:48.213'),(26.7345,'2018-07-26 12:47:48.213'),(27.2591,'2018-07-26 12:47:48.213'),(60.8154,'2018-07-26 12:47:48.213'),(60.9401,'2018-07-26 12:47:48.213'),(63.4356,'2018-07-26 12:47:48.213'),(68.1057,'2018-07-26 12:47:48.213')
,(0,'2018-07-26 12:47:48.483'),(14.7555,'2018-07-26 12:47:48.483'),(26.7345,'2018-07-26 12:47:48.483'),(27.2591,'2018-07-26 12:47:48.483'),(60.8154,'2018-07-26 12:47:48.483'),(60.9401,'2018-07-26 12:47:48.483'),(63.4356,'2018-07-26 12:47:48.483'),(68.1057,'2018-07-26 12:47:48.483')
,(0,'2018-07-26 12:48:18.483'),(21.1506,'2018-07-26 12:48:18.483'),(27.0706,'2018-07-26 12:48:18.483'),(27.1649,'2018-07-26 12:48:18.483'),(61.3094,'2018-07-26 12:48:18.483'),(61.8161,'2018-07-26 12:48:18.483'),(64.7775,'2018-07-26 12:48:18.483'),(70.0078,'2018-07-26 12:48:18.483')
,(0,'2018-07-26 12:48:48.487'),(22.8971,'2018-07-26 12:48:48.487'),(26.9688,'2018-07-26 12:48:48.487'),(27.0859,'2018-07-26 12:48:48.487'),(67.7925,'2018-07-26 12:48:48.487'),(68.5385,'2018-07-26 12:48:48.487'),(70.9347,'2018-07-26 12:48:48.487'),(72.6892,'2018-07-26 12:48:48.487')
,(0,'2018-07-26 12:49:18.487'),(23.5001,'2018-07-26 12:49:18.487'),(26.9102,'2018-07-26 12:49:18.487'),(30.5184,'2018-07-26 12:49:18.487'),(68.867,'2018-07-26 12:49:18.487'),(69.906,'2018-07-26 12:49:18.487'),(71.5178,'2018-07-26 12:49:18.487'),(84.3287,'2018-07-26 12:49:18.487')
,(0,'2018-07-26 12:49:48.490'),(23.9836,'2018-07-26 12:49:48.490'),(26.844,'2018-07-26 12:49:48.490'),(36.8819,'2018-07-26 12:49:48.490'),(71.0493,'2018-07-26 12:49:48.490'),(71.9634,'2018-07-26 12:49:48.490'),(73.7739,'2018-07-26 12:49:48.490'),(93.7401,'2018-07-26 12:49:48.490')
,(0,'2018-07-26 12:50:18.490'),(24.6327,'2018-07-26 12:50:18.490'),(26.8567,'2018-07-26 12:50:18.490'),(44.1773,'2018-07-26 12:50:18.490'),(73.4811,'2018-07-26 12:50:18.490'),(74.3621,'2018-07-26 12:50:18.490'),(76.1497,'2018-07-26 12:50:18.490'),(99.4975,'2018-07-26 12:50:18.490')


Select STime     = B.RetVal1
      ,ETime     = B.RetVal2
      ,RecCnt    = sum(1)
      ,SumVal    = sum(SomeValue)
      ,MinVal    = min(NullIf(SomeValue,0))
      ,MaxVal    = max(NullIf(SomeValue,0))
      ,AvgVal    = avg(NullIf(SomeValue,0))
 From  @YourTable  A
 Join [dbo].[tvf-Range-Date-Span]('2018-07-26','2018-07-27','SS',30) B on SomeDateTime>=RetVal1 and SomeDateTime<RetVal2 
 Group By B.RetVal1,B.RetVal2
```

**Returns**

[image]

**The Function if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Range-Date-Span] (@R1 datetime,@R2 datetime,@Part varchar(10),@Incr int)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cte0(M)   As (Select 1+Case @Part When 'YY' then DateDiff(YY,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'QQ' then DateDiff(QQ,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MM' then DateDiff(MM,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'WK' then DateDiff(WK,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'DD' then DateDiff(DD,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'HH' then DateDiff(HH,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MI' then DateDiff(MI,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'SS' then DateDiff(SS,@R1,@R2)/@Incr End),
         cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cte2(N)   As (Select Top (Select M from cte0) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte1 a,cte1 b,cte1 c,cte1 d,cte1 e,cte1 f,cte1 g,cte1 h ),
         cte3(N,D) As (Select 0,@R1 Union All Select N,Case @Part When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY,N*@Incr,@R1) When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ,N*@Incr,@R1) When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM,N*@Incr,@R1) When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK,N*@Incr,@R1) When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD,N*@Incr,@R1) When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH,N*@Incr,@R1) When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI,N*@Incr,@R1) When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS,N*@Incr,@R1) End From cte2 )

    Select RetSeq  = N+1
          ,RetVal1 = D
          ,RetVal2 = LEAD(D,1,@R2) over (Order By D)
    From   cte3,cte0 
    Where  N<cte0.M-1
)
--Max 100 million observations -- Date Parts YY QQ MM WK DD HH MI SS
--Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Range-Date-Span]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1)
```

**If it Helps with the Visualization...**

```
Select * From [dbo].[tvf-Range-Date-Span]('2018-07-26','2018-07-27','SS',30)
```

**Returns**

```
RetSeq  RetVal1                    RetVal2
1       2018-07-26 00:00:00.000    2018-07-26 00:00:30.000
2       2018-07-26 00:00:30.000    2018-07-26 00:01:00.000
3       2018-07-26 00:01:00.000    2018-07-26 00:01:30.000
4       2018-07-26 00:01:30.000    2018-07-26 00:02:00.000
5       2018-07-26 00:02:00.000    2018-07-26 00:02:30.000
....
2878    2018-07-26 23:58:30.000    2018-07-26 23:59:00.000
2879    2018-07-26 23:59:00.000    2018-07-26 23:59:30.000
2880    2018-07-26 23:59:30.000    2018-07-27 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Thank you John. I am working on it. Never seen this way before. I get the concept and just added the table-valued function. A few things regarding  ('2018-07-26', '2018-07-27','SS',30)... The first two dates need to be dynamic which I can get from my dstart and dstop. and the 30 is the dynamic parameter. Does this seem correct?

Comment: @arios Correct, all parameters in the function can be dynamic.   Either variables or column values if using a CROSS APPLY.

Comment: @arios Just a word of caution DATE1 has to <= DATE2

Comment: Roger that @John. I just pieced it together nicely. Thanks!

Comment: @arios Happy to help  :)

Answer (score 0):

I would expect something like this:

```
SELECT processval, b.processvariablename, 
       DATEDIFF(second, @DStart, a.dateentered) / @printInt, 
       0 AS vCheck ,
       COUNT(*) -- or some aggregation function
FROM procv a INNER JOIN
     procvname b 
     ON a.numid = b.numid 
WHERE a.dateentered >= @DStart AND
      a.dateentered <= @DStop AND
      b.isvisible > 0 
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(second, @DStart, a.dateentered) / @printInt, 
         processval, processvariablename ;
```

`DATEPART()` doesn't take three arguments, so this is speculating a bit on what you want.

Comment: Hey Gordon, The dateentered column is coming back as null